# PostgreSQL - counting the elements in the JSON

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a JSON type column called "log_data" and the data stored in it is in the format `[{"key":"test123123","identity":"user@test.it","identity_type":"email"}]`.

I want to count how many records for a given value for a given key in json:

**Doesn't work**

```
SELECT count (distinct esas_logs.log_id) AS "count" FROM "esas_logs" WHERE log_data->0->>'identity' = 'user@test.it'

[2016-06-30 13:59:18] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: json = unknown
  HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What type of the `esas_logs.log_id` column?

Answer (score 30):

use `json_array_length()`

```
test=# select  json_array_length('[{"key":"test123123","identity":"user@test.it","identity_type":"email"}]');
  json_array_length 
 -------------------
             1
 (1 row)
```

Comment: if the field is set as `jsonb` then use the `jsonb_array_length()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), you should use the `?` operator.

If your column type is JSON:

```
SELECT COUNT(esas_logs ? 'log_id') FROM esas_logs WHERE ...
```

If you column is a TEXT or VARCHAR:

```
SELECT COUNT(esas_logs::jsonb ? 'log_id') FROM esas_logs WHERE ...
```